# How to return array from JavaScript function that retrieves data from text file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am building a Windows 8 Store app with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I am reading in data from a text file through a function, and then putting that data into an array. I am trying to return the array through the function, but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached my code snippet.

```
// Load user data
var DefineUserData = function LoadUserData() {
return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync(loadfile).done(function (UserFile) {
   return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(UserFile).done(function (fileResult) {

       var userdata = new Object();
       var dataobject = {};
       var innercount;
       var outercount;
       var fileResultByLines = fileResult.split("\n");

       for (outercount = 0; outercount <= (fileResultByLines.length - 2) ; outercount++) {
           var tempArray = fileResultByLines[outercount].split(",");
           dataobject.metrictitle = tempArray[0];
           dataobject.numinputs = tempArray[1];
           dataobject.inputs = new Array();
           for (innercount = 0; innercount <= parseInt(dataobject.numinputs) ; innercount++) {
               dataobject.inputs[innercount] = tempArray[innercount + 2];
            }
           userdata[outercount] = dataobject;
        }               
         return userdata;
      });
   },
    function (errorResult) {
       document.getElementById("resbutton1").innerText = errorResult;
    })
}
```

Comment: Forget `return`, use callbacks. `readTextAsync` is asynchronous. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call (it's about ajax, but the logic is the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DefineUserData` function is returning a `Promise`, not a value.  Additionally `done` functions don't return anything.  Instead you'll need to use `then` functions instead of `done` functions in `DefineUserData` and then handle add a `done` function (or `then`) to the code that calls this function.

Also, You can make your promises easier to read, and easier to work with by chaining `then` functions instead of nesting them.

Currently on Win7 at the office so I can't test this, but try something similar to this pseudo-code.  Note `then` functions instead of `done`.  The last `then` returns your data.  Sample snippet afterwards to illustrate calling this and handling the result.

```
// modified version of yours
var DefineUserData = function LoadUserData() {
    return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder
        .getFileAsync(loadfile)
        .then(function (UserFile) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(UserFile);
        }).then(function (fileResult) {

            var userdata = new Object();
            var dataobject = {};
            var innercount;
            var outercount;
            var fileResultByLines = fileResult.split("\n");

            for (outercount = 0; outercount <= (fileResultByLines.length - 2) ; outercount++) {
                var tempArray = fileResultByLines[outercount].split(",");
                dataobject.metrictitle = tempArray[0];
                dataobject.numinputs = tempArray[1];
                dataobject.inputs = new Array();
                for (innercount = 0; innercount <= parseInt(dataobject.numinputs) ; innercount++) {
                    dataobject.inputs[innercount] = tempArray[innercount + 2];
                }
                userdata[outercount] = dataobject;
            }               

            return userdata;
        },
        function (errorResult) {
            document.getElementById("resbutton1").innerText = errorResult;
        });
}


// some other code...

DefineUserData.done(function (userdata) {
    // do something
});
```